# AngularJS: trying to use jsonp for cross-domain communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I'm trying to send the request for login using angular. Needs cross-domain communication, so using JSONP. Here is the code:

```
$scope.data = {"device_id":"41b72a99efb9b713","buyer_phone":"245455588","buyer_password":"mkkslkj"};
console.log($scope.data);
$scope.data = JSON.stringify($scope.data);
console.log($scope.data);
$http({
  method: 'jsonp',
  url:'https://www.application.com/app/login.php',
  data:$scope.data 
}).success(function(data, status){
    alert(data);
}) .error(function(data, status){
    console.log('Request to the API Failed');
});
```

But getting errors

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in           
<b>/home/yarnlive/public_html/yarntest/app/buyerlogin.php</b> on line   
<b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in     
<b>/home/yarnlive/public_html/yarntest/app/buyerlogin.php</b> on line   
<b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in   
<b>/home/yarnlive/public_html/yarntest/app/buyerlogin.php</b> on line   
<b>11</b><br />
{"status":"0","msg":"Invalid Username or Password","json_order":"2"}
```

Is I'm missing something, Please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for `jsonp` response, it should be like this:

```
callback({"status":"0","msg":"Invalid Username or Password","json_order":"2"})
```